# Upgrading from Python to 2.7.10 to 2.7.11 on OSX

Tags: osx, python

How can I upgrade Python from 2.7.10 to 2.7.11 on OSX (Yosemite)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/ and install it as usual:

```
sudo installer -src /path/to/python.pkg -tgt /
```

Alternately, you can use a Linux/BSD -like package manager, like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and install python from it:

```
brew update
brew install python
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
brew upgrade python
```

To upgrade from any version to latest one.